# Groovy Timestamp conversion returning incorrect values

Tags: date, groovy, timestamp, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a timestamp to a date with format DD/MM/YYYY using Groovy

To do this, I initially get a Timestamp value returned from a database query. It has the format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.S (the .S is actually a milisecond I guess)
```

So I create a new variable and use the getTime() method to convert it to miliseconds as follows:

```
def long myDate = theDate.getTime()
```

Now, a few examples of what I get here is: [Added two fields so you can see what im converting]

```
theDate (timeStamp)     myDate (time in milis)

1987-01-23 00:00:00.0 : 538358400000        
1959-08-26 00:00:00.0 : -326682000000       
1982-12-31 00:00:00.0 : 410140800000
```

Noww hen I try to create a new Date in the format DD/MM/YYYY using

```
def dt = new Date(myDate)
dt = dt.format("DD/MM/YYYY")
```

which is ultimately what I need I get the following values:

```
theDate (timeStamp)     myDate (time in milis)     new formatted date

1987-01-23 00:00:00.0 : 538358400000          :    23/01/1987  (Perfect)
1959-08-26 00:00:00.0 : -326682000000         :    238/08/1959 (Day is off)
1982-12-31 00:00:00.0 : 410140800000          :    365/12/1982 (Day is off)
```

So my question is why is this returning strange values and what do I need to change to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the date format should be

```
dd/MM/yyyy
```

And you get negative milliseconds because millis is calculated from the epoch which is `1st Jan 1970`. Any date before that will yield negative millis value.

The actual format with timestamp would be

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Note caps `M` for month and `m` for minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll test it out in the morning and upvote etc

Answer (score 1):

dmahapatro gives the right answer. Look at http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format%28java.lang.String%29 pointing at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html "Date and Time Patterns" and you see DD is for the day of the year, while dd is for the day of the month - the one you want.

Comment: Thanks for the doc links. Useful